# Neo4j - shortestPath at Each Level upto N-Levels

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to find the best path between two nodes. I am following two ways

1. find a shortest path using shortestPath() method
2. find all paths and filter the best path using reduce function

In the first method, the shortestPath() returns the path with lesser degrees of separation. While the second path returns the path which is lesser in the aggregated value.

```
Example 1:
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
MATCH path=shortestPath((a)-[r*]-(b)) 
RETURN path


Example 2:    
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
MATCH path=(a)-[r*]-(b)
WITH path, REDUCE(distance=0, r IN relationships(path)|distance+r.distance) AS WEIGHT     
RETURN path ORDER BY WEIGHT
```

But In either the case I am unable to find best path at each level. That is
For 1st degree separation - one path
Second degree separation - one path
Third degree separation - one path Like wise.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for each length of the path(s) you want to know what is the lowest weighted path?

Does this give you what you want:

```
// Match on all pairs of Person nodes
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
// Find all paths in the graph
MATCH path=(a)-[r*]-(b)
// Get length of path and reduce to calculate weighted distance for each path
WITH length(path) AS len, path, REDUCE(distance=0, r IN relationships(path)|distance+r.distance) AS WEIGHT ORDER BY WEIGHT
// group by length of path and return lowest weighted path for each length
RETURN len, collect(path)[0] AS paths ORDER BY len
```

**Edit**

As Gabor points out in his comment, the above approach is very inefficient and does not scale to large graphs. For large graphs you should use a graph search algorithm such as Dijkstra, which is available from Cypher with [Neo4j's APOC procedueres](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress). For example:

```
MATCH (from:Person{name:'A'}), (to:Person{name:'D'})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(from, to, 'KNOWS', 'distance') yield path as path, weight as weight
RETURN path, weight
```

Comment: This solution works for small graphs, but if you want reasonable performance, consider using [APOC graph algorithms](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress).